# How to present a macOS file system dialog using native SwiftUI in a MenuBarExtra scene?

Tags: macos, swiftui

Is it possible to present the macOS file system dialog using SwiftUI such as [`fileExporter`/`fileImporter`/`fileMover`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/modal-presentations) in a `MenuBarExtra` scene? If yes, then how?

The following code snippet works in the context of a `WindowGroup` scene `Menu` `Button`:

```swift
@State private var showMover = false
@State private var url = URL.desktopDirectory.appending(
    component: "MOVEME.txt", 
    directoryHint: .notDirectory)

// …

Button("Move File") { showMover.toggle() }
    .fileMover(isPresented: $showMover, file: url) { result in
        print("onCompletion callback result: \(result)")
    }
```

The app will compile and launch when the same code is used in a `MenuBarExtra` scene. However, the system file browser window *does not show* and the `onCompletion` routine *does not execute* when the `Menu` control `Button` is selected.

Although, the use of `NSOpenPanel` and `NSSavePanel` provide a possible non-SwiftUI workaround, this question is focused on finding a SwiftUI native solution if/when possible.

Is there *some SwiftUI native* way to present the system file dialog in a `MenuBarExtra` context?